# Allocating std vector content with dynamic objects

Tags: c++, malloc, std, stdvector

I have a
`std::vector< MyObject* > my_vector;`
Which is not empty and i want to allocate and push a certain amount of MyObject* in it.
I know the number of objects to push. Is there a better way (optimized/faster) to do it than:

```
int object_count = 10000;
for(int index = 0; index < object_count; index++)
{
    my_vector.push_back(new MyObject());
}
```

Like allocating in one call of malloc for all the MyObject and then memcpy the result to my_vector.
Any idea?

**Update**
My issue is the call to new 10000 times. I want to be able to allocate one big chunk of memory and swaping the memory to the end of my_vector.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using pointers and `new`? With `vector<MyObject>` you can simply use `resize` (or a suitable constructor) to add default-constructed objects.

Comment: Yes because the objects I push are specializations of MyObject.

Comment: @Silouane: OK, fair enough.

Comment: my_vector is not empty thus I can not construct it with the sizing constructor.

Comment: he just said to use reserve

Comment: @DonLarynx it's not the std::vector memory my problem, but the call to new every loop step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just reserve enough space in vector, so it will allocate memory only once. Also it is a good practice to use std::unique_ptr<>:

```
std::vector<std::unqiue_ptr<MyObject> > my_vector;
int object_count = 10000;
my_vector.reserve(object_count);
for(int index = 0; index < object_count; index++)
{
  my_vector.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject()));
}
```

**Update**: if you can not use (or don't want to) use unique_ptr, just add reserve to your code to preallocate memory.

**Update 2**: as far as I understood, you want to avoid memory allocation in `new MyObject()`. One possible solution to do it is the following (not intended for real application use):

```
// a very simple example
class Pool {
public:
  Pool() : array(new MySpecObjects[10000]), counter(10000); {}
  MySpecObject* get() {
    --counter;
    return array[counter];
  }
  void reset() {
    counter = 10000;
  }
  MySpecObject* array;
  size_t counter;
};

static Pool* getPool() {
  static Pool pool;
  return pool;
}

std::vector<MyObject* > my_vector;
int object_count = 10000;
my_vector.reserve(object_count);
for(int index = 0; index < object_count; index++) {
  my_vector.push_back(getPool().get()));
}
```

It is a simplified example, it's not thread safe and Pool will clear it's memory at program shutdown. The idea behind it is similar to the [flyweight gof pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), [see boost for example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html)

**Update 3**: maybe a better solution is to use [intrusive lists](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html) here. Then, all you need to do is to preallocate vectors of objects:

```
class MyObject : public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
  ...
};
// MySpecObject1 and MySpecObject2 inherit MyObject
std::vector<MySpecObject1> objs1(10000);
std::vector<MySpecObject2> objs2(10000);
...

typedef boost::intrusive::list<MyObject> BaseList;

BaseList list;
for (MyObject& ref : objs1) {
  list.push_back(ref);
}
for (MyObject& ref : objs2) {
  list.push_back(ref);
}
```

Note that BaseList doesn't own its nodes. When you do push_back to it, list just links an object to the existing list, no allocation is performed.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly updated my answer, OP can just ignore unique_ptr.

Comment: But my main concern is the call to new every loop increment.
It's what cost a lot in my program, and I would like to know if I can call only one new MyObject[10000] and copy the result to my_vector?

Comment: @Silouane so why don't you just store objects in vector by value `std::vector<MyObject>`? Is it an option for you?

Comment: @PavelDavydov because I store specializations of MyObject.

Comment: @Silouane so MyObject is an interface for some polymorphic objects that you want to store in vector?

Comment: @PavelDavydov Yes that's the case.

Comment: @Silouane can you use c++11? The problem here is that objects inherited from interface can have different sizes. So you have to implement a custom [memory allocator](https://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html) and then use it to manage memory for `new MyObject()`.

Comment: @PavelDavydov I can use c++11. But I know that the next 10000 MyObject are of the same specialization objects let say MySpecObject. But before and after in the vector can be stored other specializations. Do you understand?

Comment: @Silouane yes, I think I understand. See my update. The code there is just to show the idea, obviously it is not the best solution, but it is simple.

Comment: @PavelDavydov Thanks for the real help. I'll try this solution and monitor the performances. I let you know the result.

Comment: @Silouane see my update number 3, the idea is to use intrusive lists, if it is acceptable.

Comment: @PavelDavydov Interesting solution, I'll keep it in mind, but the pool is the one I'll use for my current problem. Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard function [`std::generate_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/) that seem to fit your needs:

```
// Reserve space in vector to prevent unneeded reallocations
my_vector.reserve(my_vector.capacity() + 10000);
// Use back inserter to automatically call push_back each time 
// generate_n assigns value. Lambda will be called at each iteration
// constructing new object.
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(my_vector), 10000, 
            []() { return new MyObject; });
```